# Can I share drafts when Draft Item Security is enabled

Tags: document-library, permissions, document, share, draft

I have a document library in SharePoint that has Major and Minor (draft) revisions. Before any document is published, it has to be reviewed and approved by someone. Normally I would use the collect feedback or the approval workflow, but I am working in the 2016 beta so the license is expired (certain features like workflows don't work) and the person in charge of it won't update to the trial, he plans to wait for the official release.

The problem I am having is that the people who should review the documents don't (and shouldn't) have the Edit permissions, so they can't view the drafts they are supposed to review. Is there a way to Share drafts with them (in SharePoint) without giving them Edit permissions or only giving them temporary permissions on a per-document basis? Ideally I want to share the documents rather than create a group, because the reviewers can change and it defeats the purpose of hiding the drafts if every potential reviewer (which could be my entire ENG department) can see drafts. That being said, if using a group will work to allow certain users to view drafts with Draft Item Security on, I will gladly accept that as a solution.

I tried using the Share feature and selecting **Can Edit**, but that didn't allow them to see the document I was linking them to. I also referenced [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Specify-who-can-view-drafts-c3bfc744-c4a4-4691-b506-42b338312c21), but it doesn't help with what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue and the only solution I found is to manually elevate permissions for people who are to review separate files.

Refer to this article for a bit more details - https://www.google.ca/amp/s/spandcrm.com/2016/04/18/how-to-share-access-to-hidden-draft-documents-in-sharepoint-2013/amp/

I believe a variation of this solution is embedded into the standard approval workflows that make the permisdions magic in the background.